# R googleway: using a different palette

Tags: r, googleway

Is it possible to use a non viridisLite palette with googleway?  Specifically, I want to have a single colour scale.  Here is my attempt:

```
library(googleway)
library(RColorBrewer)
googleway::google_map("") %>% 
  googleway::add_polygons(data = melbourne, 
               polyline = "polyline", 
               fill_colour = "SA4_NAME", 
               palette = brewer.pal(9, "Purples")
               )
```

Result:

```
Error in checkPalettes.default(arg) : 
  I don't recognise the type of palette you've supplied
```

Answer (score 1):

The `palette` argument is expecting a function which generates a palette given a single argument as input (not a palette of colours itself)

You can wrap the `brewer.pal()` function in your own function with a single input.

However, the trouble you're going to face is mapping the 9 colours from brewer.pal to the 12 `SA4_NAME` variables. 9 into 12 doesn't go.

This is how it would work if you had a variable with 9 different values.

```
library(googleway)
library(RColorBrewer)

set_key(read.dcf("~/Documents/.googleAPI", fields = "GOOGLE_MAP_KEY"))

myBrewerPal <- function(x) { brewer.pal(n = x, name = "Purples") }
melbourne$myVal <- sample(1:9, size = nrow(melbourne), replace = T)

googleway::google_map("") %>% 
  googleway::add_polygons(
    data = melbourne
    , polyline = "polyline"
    , fill_colour = "myVal"
    , palette = myBrewerPal
    )
```

[image]

---

An alternative solution is to manually add a column of hex colours to `melbourne`, and specify that column as the `fill_colour`. Then it's up to you to make sure the colours are mapped correctly to the variables you want.

```
melbourne$myColours <- sample(brewer.pal(n = 9, name = "Purples"), size = nrow(melbourne), replace = T)

googleway::google_map("") %>% 
  googleway::add_polygons(
    data = melbourne
    , polyline = "polyline"
    , fill_colour = "myColours"
  )
```

Comment: Since `brewer.pal` only does 9 colours, I've created a rank, rescaled and rounded to 1:9 and am passing that to the palette function.  It gets around dealing with abnormally large values that make the other polygons look almost the same colour.
` ... %>% mutate(rank = round(rescale(dense_rank(myVariable), to=c(1,9))))`